# How can PHP's foreach() be successfully nested on a single array?

Tags: php-internals

Consider the following code:

```php
$a = [1, 2, 3];

foreach ($a as $x) {
    foreach ($a as $y) {
        echo "$x $y\n";
    }
}
```

As one would expect, it gives the following result:

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 1
3 2
3 3
```

Although happy with the result, I'm surprised it works, because according to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), it relies on the array's internal pointer:

> When foreach first starts executing, the internal array pointer is automatically reset to the first element of the array. This means that you do not need to call reset() before a foreach loop.
>
> As foreach relies on the internal array pointer, changing it within the loop may lead to unexpected behavior.

So we could expect that using a nested `foreach` inside the first one, would share the same internal pointer, and produce the following result:

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
```

Because the first `foreach` would see the state of the internal pointer left by the nested `foreach`.

I can think of two possible explanations to the actual behaviour:

- The PHP manual is wrong / outdated, and PHP uses a separate pointer specific to every `foreach`;
- The nested `foreach` internally triggers a duplication of the array in memory, so they would each have their own pointer.

Just for my culture, **how does this work internally?**

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works/14854568#14854568

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer. PHP indeed copies the array (that is, the array *structure*) in this situation. Foreach can do that in various scenarios to prevent problems like this. Some people believe that foreach *always* copies the array, but that is not the case (that would be inefficient).

I found a great blog post that describes this behavior in more detail:

[PHP internals: When does foreach copy?](https://nikic.github.io/2011/11/11/PHP-Internals-When-does-foreach-copy.html)

The summary:

- `foreach` will copy the array *structure* if and only if the iterated
  array is not referenced and has a refcount > 1
- `foreach` will
  additionally copy the array *values* if and only if the previous point
  applies and the iteration is done by reference